# dm-tool switch-to-user [username] switches off screen light

Tags: xubuntu, lightdm, xfce

This happens on a Lenovo T400 laptop running xubuntu 16.04, currently with kernel 4.10.0-32-generic x86_64.

The current version of lightdm is 1.18.3.

If I use my starter on the xfce4 panel which is bound to

```
dm-tool switch-to-user userA
```

in order to switch to another user, the screen turns black. It looks like the screen illumination is switched off. Even on a complete black screen I usually see a bit of light shining close to the screen frame, but in this situatin this is off.

In such a situation I can use Ctl+Alt+F1 to switch to a console (and the screen light goes on!)

I can log in selecting a user name and password or alternatively press Ctl+Alt+F7 to switch back to the GUI of my old session.

**It looks like dm-tool falsely switches off the screen light.** The dialog to enter the password might even be present, but how can one tell if the screen is black?

Comment: also after dm-tool switch-to-greeter the screen illumination turns off.

Comment: From an open session of userA after dm-tool switch-to-user userB (another user), I can enter userB's password when the screen is black and this returns me to the open session of userA. There seems to be a bug in dm-tool.